# On Linux, Debugging a C++ application with gdb in Eclipse CDT, how to input something to stdin?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, stdin, eclipse-cdt

On Linux, I am trying to debug a C++ application with gdb in Eclipse CDT.

For example the application `applic.exe` takes some command line arguments `arg1` and `arg2` and it expects some data on `stdin` (say, taken from a file `input.txt`).

Normally, to run the application in the console I would do this:

```
cat input.txt | applic.exe arg1 arg2
```

Using gdb in the console I can do:

```
gdb applic.exe
(gdb) run applic.exe arg1 arg2 < input.txt
```

Is it possible to do that with gdb in Eclipse? I know how to specify the arguments (and the environment) in the Eclipse *Debug Configurations*, but what about `stdin`?

Comment: I am not sure if that can be done, in the run configuration there is an option for specifying an output file, but for input it says that it needs to have a console attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Console tab in Eclipse (at the bottom of IDE) you can put your data here.

Comment: Make sure you select the gdb console from the consoles that are available.

Comment: I think the op is asking for an automatic way of doing that, not copying and pasting every time (it might be a very large input file!)

Comment: Then what about passing file name as a parameter, and open it for read inside the program?

Comment: Yes, that can used as a workaround. But I would have preferred not to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of entering the redirection in the arguments tab, append it to the executable file name in the debug configuration.