# How to allocate an input file instead of the stdin in an Eclipse CDT application?

Tags: c, debugging, configuration, eclipse-cdt, stdin

My application is a simple executable used from the command line and takes `stdin` as input and `stdout` as output, so it behaves like many GNU tools.
To test it, I want to set up an *Eclipse CDT DEBUG Configuration* to pass a file to `stdin` and another one to `stdout`.

I have tried unsuccessfully a few solutions, all inside the `DEBUG Configuration` GUI :

1. In `Common / Standard Input and Output / Input File:` I put `inputfile.txt` and in the same section `Output file:` I put `outputfile.txt`. As the GUI indicates that the working directory is `${workspace_loc:/myprogram}`, it should be alright, but when the debugger is started, it warns :

`[Invalid file specified for console output: test/WittenACM87ArithmCoding-1.txt.coded]
[Invalid file specified for  stdin file: test/WittenACM87ArithmCoding-1.txt]`

3. In `Arguments` I put `< inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt` which is obviously not designed for that

Of course, both files are in the working directory. All attempts fails on the `ch = getc(stdin);` code line with some strange message:

`Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-p3Km7c/glibc-2.24/io/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.`

Here is the stack:

`Thread #1 [myprogram] 31960 [core: 5] (Suspended : Signal : SIGINT:Interrupt)

    __read_nocancel() at /build/glibc-p3Km7c/glibc-2.24/io/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84 0x7ffff7811700 
    _IO_new_file_underflow() at /build/glibc-p3Km7c/glibc-2.24/libio/fileops.c:600 0x7ffff77a9a00

    __GI__IO_default_uflow() at /build/glibc-p3Km7c/glibc-2.24/libio/genops.c:413 0x7ffff77aab02

    _IO_getc() at /build/glibc-p3Km7c/glibc-2.24/libio/getc.c:38 0x7ffff77a54f0 
    main() at /xxxxxx/src/myprogram.c:20 0x555555554f01`

When I run the application directly in the console, it works:

`./myprogram < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

I assume from this that Eclipse does not manage to realise the files redirections to `stdin` and `stdout`, so obviously, I do it the wrong way. I have searched for it, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851881/on-linux-debugging-a-c-application-with-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt-how-to-input-some) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574596/eclipse-cdt-mars-input-from-a-file) don't provide solution for my use case.

So, in order to be able to use the debugger from Eclipse, what is the right way to set up the Eclipse `DEBUG Configuration` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, solution 1 was using a relative path not related to the working directory. Using either button `Workspace...` or `File System...` in the GUI enables to select the files which shall already exist.

For example with Workspace definition, the field becomes :

`${workspace_loc:/myprogram/inputfile.txt}` (same for output)

And it works. Debuggers says :

`[Console output redirected to file:/.../myprogram/outputfile.txt]`